# A question about proving maximal ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Let $R$ be the subring of the real numbers such that $R=\left\{a+b\sqrt{2}:a,b \in \Bbb Z\right\}$ Let $M$ be the ideal in $R$ given by $M=\left\{a+b\sqrt{2}:\text{ a and b are divisible by 5}\right\}$ Prove that $M$is a maximal ideal of $R$.

I was thinking that suppose $M \subseteq P\subseteq R$ and prove that $1\in P$ but I don't know how to prove that. Hope somebody can help me with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume that $M$ is not maximal.  So $M\subset P\subset R$.  Let $a\in P$, with $a$ an integer such that $5$ does not divide $a$.  We have that $5\in M\subset P$.  By the ideal property this means that $5+a\in P$.  But we also have that $\gcd(5,a)=1$.  So we know there exists an integer combination of $5$ and $a$ summing to 1.  Say

$$5n+am=1 $$

$5n,am\in P$  Therefore, since an ideal is closed under addition we have that $1\in P$ and therefore, $P=R$.  Therefore, no proper ideal of $R$ contains $M$.  Also, $M$ is not the whole ring because it doesn't contain $1$.  Thus $M$ is maximal.  I feel like there may be a hole to be found, so I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: In fact I really don't think my answer works, because $5$ is not in $M$.

Comment: yes it is: $\;5=5+0\sqrt2\;,\;\;5\mid 5\;,\;5\mid 0\;$

Comment: Ok.  I don't know why I was thinking $5$ didn't divide zero...Thanks.

Comment: I don't think you can assume such an $a$ exists.

Comment: If no such $a$ existed, then $M$ would be maximal from the start.

Comment: Wait.  I see a complication.  the element $5+\sqrt{2}$ could be an element in $P$ and not in $M$.  So yeah, my $a$ need not exist.  Dang.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following :

1. Prove that $(x^2-2) \in \mathbb{Z}_5[x]$ is irreducible, and let $F = \mathbb{Z}_5[x]/(x^2-2)$ be the corresponding quotient, which is a field.
2. Define a surjective homomorphism $\varphi : R\to F$ such that $\ker\varphi = M$.